# Java Spring Boot cannot use LocalDateTime from .json file

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-time, java-17

I develop an applicaiton using mock json data here is the format:

Edit: I dont use spring data jpa in my project.

```
 {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Video 1",
    "duration": "10:30",
    "description": "A sample video",
    "url": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/example-bucket/video1.mp4",
    "createdAt": "2022-11-11T10:08:29.973058478",
    "creatorId": 101,
    "category": "Technology",
    "view": 115,
    "like": 23,
    "dislike": 5
  }
```

And here is my Video class.

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Video {
    private Integer id;
    private String title;
    private String duration; // as miliseconds
    private String description;
    private String url;
    private String createdAt;
    private Integer creatorId;
    private String category;
    private Integer view;
    private Integer like;
    private Integer dislike;
}
```

Whenever I change created at to LocalDateTime type, it is broken. It says:

```
Failed to instantiate [ozancinci.video.VideoRepository]: Constructor threw exception
```

What might be the issue? Only time it brokes is when I change the type to LocalDateTime. When I make it String type, error goes away.

I am searching solutions for 1 hour but I couldnt find anything solid.

Comment: By the way, if you want to track "createdAt" accurately, you would use `java.time.Instant`, `OffsetDateTime`, or `ZonedDateTime` class rather than `LocalDateTime`. Include an indicator of offset (and optionally time zone). Generally best to record such text with an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds. In standard ISO 8601 format, the `Z` on the end will indicate an offset of zero. See `Instant.parse` & `Instant#toString`.

Comment: Hi @BasilBourque, I was trying to implement a hands-on java task that is given to me by a company that I applied for as a Jr. Java Developer. Since the deadline was due before you sent the answer and I couldnt find any solution that time, I stored date as string and then used parser for date comparison for sorting. May I ask how bad practice is it? I tried to explain it in my solutions with comment lines but I didnt feel allright to do so. (Note: The task wanted me to use .json file as data collection so I wasnt using a real db for my solution)

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell the JSON library you are using with Spring how to parse the `createdAt` field.

If you are using Jackson then the `JsonFormat` annotation would do the trick if you really want `LocalDateTime` but as the first comment suggested there are better alternatives like `Instant` or `ZonedDateTime` which will also work with the following:

```java
...

@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS")
private LocalDateTime createdAt;

...
```

if you are using GSON you need to write a deserializer like:

```java
class MyDateDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<LocalDateTime> {

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        return LocalDateTime.parse(json.getAsString(), DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"));
    }
}
```

and then in your class you need to annotate your field (I left out any validations so it's easier to follow/understand):

```java
...

@JsonAdapter(MyDateDeserializer.class)
private LocalDateTime createdAt;

...
```

I haven't used GSON in a very long time so there might be an easier way but this should work as well.

PS. I would also discourage you to use Lombok because once it gets entangled into a project is almost impossible to get rid of. Just let your IDE generate the getters, setters, constructors, equals methods, hash codes etc.

Comment: Hello, I was trying to implement a hands-on java task that is given to me by a company that I applied for as a Jr. Java Developer. Since the deadline was due before you sent the answer and I couldnt find any solution that time, I stored date as string and then used parser for date comparison for sorting. May I ask how bad practice is it? I tried to explain it in my solutions with comment lines but I didnt feel allright to do so. (Note: The task wanted me to use .json file as data collection so I wasnt using a real db for my solution)